# Why is django filling spaces to the max length of the char field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have some char fields in django that look like this:

```
attrunit = models.CharField(db_column='AttributeUnit', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
```

To my understanding, the blank option allows users to write empty form values, and null means the entry does not need to be populated at all in the database. However, whenever I write to *any* of my CharFields, django seems to backfill spaces up to the max length of the field. For reference, I routed all of my write-models into a MSSQL server database (not the default SQLLite db that django builds). I'm at a loss as to where these spaces are coming from and I do not want to have to strip the values every time I read them out from the db.

Answer (score 1):

Today I learned the difference between nchar and nvarchar, my bad, sorry~!